# How to append value to the same key in python using pipe delimiter

Tags: python

I'm reading a text file which I will convert into array of (key,pairs). I want to append the values if I have same key with pipe delimiter. I'm new to python, can someone please help me to fix this issue. Please find my code and input and output format:

File Input: (test.txt)

```
1234567 E29dceffb-28bd-4f05-b91f-03f05510c081,0743,438864,10/06/2016,7,IK,PP,7136977,,4,37791,,,,01/11/2017
83738383 E29dceffb-38373-3839-8393-83038383,0743,438864,10/06/2016,7,PO,VC,4,37791,,,,01/11/2017
1234567 E29dceffb-38DFG3-4f05-0393-39303933,1234,78789,10/06/2016,7,LL,YY,7136977,,4,37791,,,01/10/2017
```

Python code:

```
import sys

with open('test.txt') as f:
  result = dict(line.split(' ', 1) for line in f)
  for line in list:
    if line[0] in result:
        result[line[0]].append(line[1])
    else:
        result[line[0]] = [line[1]]
```

I want to print my key and value like below:

```
Key: 1234567.AB.K
Value: E29dceffb-28bd-4f05-b91f-03f05510c081,0743,438864,10/06/2016,7,IK,PP,7136977,,4,37791,,,,01/11/2017|E29dceffb-38DFG3-4f05-0393-39303933,1234,78789,10/06/2016,7,LL,YY,7136977,,4,37791,,,01/10/2017|

Key: 83738383.AB.K
Value: E29dceffb-38373-3839-8393-83038383,0743,438864,10/06/2016,7,PO,VC,4,37791,,,,01/11/2017|
```

Using pipe delimiter if more than one value occurs for same key to differentiate first record, second record and so on.

I'll be getting around 2 millions of entry in test.txt file.

How efficiently I can handle this in python. My python script is not working as expected its breaking the code if i try to append the value for same key.

Any help is very much appreciated!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For line in list:?  What is that?  I don't think you want to create the dict for each line, so move the for line in f outside that.

Comment: I think result should be a list, and you use for line in result (instead of list) and do checking if line[0] in temp_dict.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your `list` on that `for` loop.

The reason your code break when you try to append the value for same key is because you create `result` as dictionary with each value being a single string.

What you need is to create a `result_dict` for your final result, something like this

```
result_dict = {}

with open('test.txt') as f:
  lines = list(line.split(' ', 1) for line in f)
  for line in lines:
    if line[0] in result_dict:
        result_dict[line[0]].append(line[1].strip())
    else:
        result_dict[line[0]] = [line[1].strip()]

print(result_dict)
```

will print

```
{'1234567.AB.K': ['E29dceffb-28bd-4f05-b91f-03f05510c081,0743,438864,10/06/2016,7,IK,PP,7136977,,4,37791,,,,01/11/2017', 'E29dceffb-38DFG3-4f05-0393-39303933,1234,78789,10/06/2016,7,LL,YY,7136977,,4,37791,,,01/10/2017'], '83738383.AB.K': ['E29dceffb-38373-3839-8393-83038383,0743,438864,10/06/2016,7,PO,VC,4,37791,,,,01/11/2017']}
```

Comment: Thanks Pangeran! But this code is breaking if key has more than two values. Its giving index out of range. And how to append pipe to differentiate first and second record?

Comment: The only suspect if its giving index out of range is line[1]. Are you sure your data format is consistent (key [space] value)?

Comment: Yes data format is consistent, but same key will have different set of values. And want to append all value with pipe delimiter. As I mentioned in my post output.

Comment: The case on same key has multiple values already handled. Using sample test.txt from you, my code print as shown in my answer. Do you mind upload test.txt you using? Regarding using pipe delimiter, you can use join, refer to this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm